# Sleuth traceId and spanId not logged in activeMQ Listener

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm trying to configure a microservice with Sleuth and ActiveMQ.
When starting a request I can properly see appName, traceId and spanId in logs of producer, but after dequeuing the message in listener I find only appName, without traceId and spanId.
How can I get this fields filled?

Right now I'm working with spring.sleuth.messaging.jms.enabled=false to avoid this exception at startup:

- Bean named 'connectionFactory' is expected to be of type 'org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.messaging.LazyConnectionFactory'

My dependencies:

- org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-activemq 2.5.1
- org.springframework.cloud.spring-cloud-sleuth 3.0.3

Thank you all!

Comment: Not sure to understand your questions. These properties are automatically injected in logs by spring sleuth, so i need no settings apart adding dependencies, but I don't retrieve them in logs after broker release the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the properties you're looking for are set *on the JMS message* when the message is sent and then retrieved from the message when it is consumed. Since you're setting `spring.sleuth.messaging.jms.enabled=false` you're disabling this functionality. See [the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-sleuth/2.1.0.M2/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_spring_jms) which states:

> We instrument the `JmsTemplate` so that tracing headers get injected into the message. We also support `@JmsListener` annotated methods on the consumer side.
>
> To block this feature, set `spring.sleuth.messaging.jms.enabled` to `false`.

You'll need to find an alternate solution for the connection factory problem if you want to use Sleuth with Spring JMS. If you're injecting `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` somewhere then you should almost certainly be using `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` instead. Using the concrete type is bad for portability and use-cases like this where wrapper implementations are used dynamically.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I had to disable that functionality exactly for conflicts with ActiveMQConnectionFactory. I'll try following your suggestions and use ConnectionFactory. Thank you